# MYSQL convert float to datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin, type-conversion

I want to do something like this:

```
37442.3992708333 -> 05-07-2002  09:34:57
```

But when I try 'easier' syntax, I also does not work.
Like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(float, '15.6');
Result should be: 15.6
```

I always get Errors like:

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'float, '15.6')' at line 1*

I try this Syntax in xampp phpmyadmin in SQL commands.

Server Version: 5.6.20 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15
PHPMYADMIN 4.2.7.1

Comment: what is the mathematical logic behind `37442.3992708333` becoming `05-07-2002  09:34:57` ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [SEC_TO_TIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) function.

It is unclear as you haven't provided enough information what the float represents so I haven't been able to write a sample - however the documentation link above is very detailed so you should be able to work it out from there.

**Update from comment:**

If your float comes from excel then:

1. You need to research how Excel generates that float (i'm not going to do that research for you) and then reverse the process to store it as a MySQL datetime field
2. If its coming from excel can you not just create a MySQL date friendly column with a formula of `=TEXT(A3,"YYYY-MM-DD")` - changing `A3` to your cell reference to the Excel date (float)?

Comment: The float comes from importing an excel file. MS Excel stores DATETIME as float. 05.07.2002  09:34:57 would be 37442.3992708333

Comment: Thanks @Steve. At the moment I am testing your second solution.